# Clojure: convert a map with keyword keys to one with equivalent string keys

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I have a map like `{:a "A" :b "B"}` and want to convert its keys to strings, e.g. `{"a" "A" "b" "B"}`.

I have this function, which works:

```clj
(defn keyword-keys->strs [m]
  (zipmap
    (map name (keys m))
    (map second (vec m))))
```

**But is there a more idiomatic or purpose-built way to do it?**

Thanks!

Comment: `(map second (vec m)` -> `(vals m)`

Comment: simply `(reduce-kv (fn [acc k v] (assoc acc (str k) v)) {} data)`

Comment: @cfrick thanks for the tip, that was another one I had a hard time googling

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a built-in function that will recursively convert map keys to strings:

```
(clojure.walk/stringify-keys {:a "A" :b "B"})
=> {"a" "A", "b" "B"}
(clojure.walk/stringify-keys {:a "A" :b {:c "C"}})
=> {"a" "A", "b" {"c" "C"}}
```

Comment: ah, `clojure.walk`, of course! I should have looked there.

Comment: And don't forget the (more common) keywordize-keys:  https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/keywordize-keys